# Ошибка при подключении Owl-carousel

Tags: javascript, frontend, webpack

Не удаётся подключить карусель в проект. 
Сделал всё как здесь: https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2
webpack:

```
const path = require('path');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: 'public/'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: [path.join(__dirname, 'src'), path.join(__dirname, 'public')],
        watchContentBase: true,
        hotOnly: true,
        stats: "errors-only"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: ['env', 'react']
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'style-loader' // creates style nodes from JS strings
                }, {
                    loader: 'css-loader' // translates CSS into CommonJS
                }, {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            plugins: [
                                autoprefixer({
                                    browsers:['ie >= 8', 'last 4 version']
                                })
                            ],
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                    loader: 'sass-loader' // compiles Sass to CSS
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|mp3)$/i,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                loaders: ['file-loader']
            }, {
                test: /\.ico$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].[ext]'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: {
                            limit: 1000,
                            mimetype: 'application/font-woff'
                        }
                    }

                ]
            }, {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                loader: 'file-loader'
            }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
        }),
    ],
};
```

В index.js добавил:

```
import 'owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css';
import 'owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.css';
import 'owl.carousel';
```

В консоле такая ошибка:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.css
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (9:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|  *    Default theme - Owl Carousel CSS File
|  */
| .owl-theme .owl-nav {
|   margin-top: 10px;
|   text-align: center;
 @ ./src/index.js 15:0-57
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/only-dev-server ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (9:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|  *  Owl Carousel - Core
|  */
| .owl-carousel {
|   display: none;
|   width: 100%;
 @ ./src/index.js 13:0-52
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/only-dev-server ./src/index.js
```

Зависимости:

```
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "isotope-layout": "^3.0.5",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "owl.carousel": "^2.3.2",
    "pe7-icon": "^1.0.4",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас же в webpack.config.js  стоит расширение SCSS **test: /.scss$/,** почему после этого вы подключаете через import `СSS` файлы.

У вас ошибка говорит для того чтобы исправить это вы должны загрузить подходящий **loader** чтобы справитсья с данной расширением **CSS**.

Если не хотите ничего загружать просто в `node_modules` выберите `SCSS` файл  в папке `owl-carousel`

Можете через scss это сделать таким образом

```
@import "node_modules/owl.carousel/src/scss/owl.carousel.scss";
```

Или же через **js**

```
 import 'owl.carousel/src/scss/owl.carousel.scss';
```